# How to upload a file to S3 as a Cognito user by using aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-amplify

I got an 403 error when I tried to [upload to S3 with Amplify.js](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/) and I can't figure out why...

So I'd like to see if I get the same 403 error with aws-cli, but I don't know how to upload a file ***as a Cognito user*** by using aws-cli.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something to check: Cognito user profile has the right permissions to upload to the S3 bucket. This has tripped me up before. "was s3 cp" is what you are looking for.

```
aws s3 cp <local_file_path> s3://<bucket_name>/<s3_object_key> --profile <cognito_user_profile>
```

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: How can I get the `cognito_user_profile` ? Can you provide me more details? Thanks!